# How to create a directory with the date that is 30 days older then the current date

Tags: python, operating-system

I used the following function to create a directory based on today's date:
`os.mkdirs(time.strftime('%y%m%d'),exist_ok=True)`
how to subtract 30 days from the current date?

I am expecting the directory to be `2023/01/31` if today's date is `2023/03/03`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
import os, datetime

os.makedirs((datetime.datetime.now()
            -datetime.timedelta(days=30)
            ).strftime('%y%m%d'), exist_ok=True)
```

*NB. for the YYYY/MM/DD format, use `strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`, but this is not valid for all operating systems.*

Comment: did you `import datetime`, not `from datetime import datetime`?, you can also use `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and remove the leading `datetime` from the commands ;)

Comment: Yeah Thanks Actually i want the directory like 2023/01/31 but now my directory is 20230131

Comment: Have you read the note? "*for the YYYY/MM/DD format, use strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), but this is not valid for all operating systems*"

Comment: Your knowledge is excellent. Thanks brother